# Configuring X-Frame-Options Response Header on AWS CloudFront and S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, x-frame-options

I'd like to add `X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header for static content hosted on Amazon S3 with a Cloudfront cache. How can I add these headers?

Answer (score 12):

You can add the x-frame-options header to the response from CloudFront / S3 using a [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html) function. The lambda code runs within the local edge locations, but needs to be created and maintained in the `us-east-1` region.

The example code here uses nodeJS 6.10 to add the response header

```
'use strict'; 
 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   const response = event.Records[0].cf.response; 
   const headers = response.headers; 
   response.headers['x-frame-options'] = [{"key":"X-Frame-Options","value":"SAMEORIGIN"}]; 
   console.log(response.headers); 
   callback(null, response);
 };
```

Create a definitive version of the Lambda, then set the Lambda Version's trigger configuration as the CloudFront `origin-response` Event type for your path pattern behavior.

The example code logs events to CloudWatch logs service for debugging purposes. If you don't already have one you will need to setup a lambda execution IAM role that allows a policy allowing CloudWatch logs actions to be assumed by `edgelambda.amazonaws.com` and `lambda.amazonaws.com`.

Basic Lambda Execution Policy allowing logs to be written to CloudWatch:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust Relationship allowing Lambda and Lambda@Edge to assume the role :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "edgelambda.amazonaws.com",
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

It would be better if AWS simply allowed the x-frame-options header to be set in the GUI but until then this solution works and will allow you to keep your Security Auditors happy.

Comment: Hey, what trigger would you choose on the cloudfront event end?

Comment: also is it possible to do using python?

Comment: Now it can be done on GUI using Response Header Policies. Check this out -- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-response-headers-policies/

Answer (score 4):

It is now possible to use SecurityHeaders via CloudFront

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-http-security-headers/

Which include:

x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN

x-content-type-options: nosniff

strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can set the headers in the $http angular service like so:

```
$http(method: '<TYPE>', headers: headers, url: <URL>, data: {}).success(...);
var headers = {'X-Frame-Options': ...};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Mo Binni,but what i need is to set it in the server side so when the page loads the browser should not be allowed to render it in a frame or iframe

Comment: Something related to this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=660139&#660139

Comment: Oooh what kind of server are you running?

Comment: it's Cloudfront serving from an s3

Comment: Oh okay sorry, thought it was an angular specific question - fail