# Google chrome does not show PDF files in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, pdf.js

I use Pdf.js, I get base64 file from web service (this.attachmentSource), and when I want to add `var iframe =  "<iframe width=800 height=550 src='" + this.attachmentSource + "' > </iframe>`",For some pdfs in google chrome I get iframe empty, but in Mozila everything work fine, who can explain this mystery?

Comment: have you tried with <object type="application/pdf" data="yourSource"></object> ?

Comment: What if you don't add the src in the HTML and instead add it after you've attached the element to the DOM via JavaScript?

Comment: @Diego yes I tried object, same result.

Comment: @apokryfos in mozila it worked fine, I think it can not be that issue.

Comment: Is your data source properly formatted according to [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)?

Comment: @apokryfos yes everything formatted like in a spec, and I check some pds work normal another ones nope, I will edit my question, because this problem for some specific pdfs only.

Answer (score 5):

I happened to notice: server Response Header:

```
x-frame-options: DENY
```

The DENY option is the most secure, preventing any use of the current page in a frame. More commonly, SAMEORIGIN is used.

I was using AWS CloudFront with a Lambda@Edge function already, so I found a solution here: [Configuring X-Frame-Options Response Header on AWS CloudFront and S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144580/configuring-x-frame-options-response-header-on-aws-cloudfront-and-s3)

If you are using a different server stack, you will have to adjust your server response headers accordingly.

Comment: ✅ This should probably be the accepted answer for at least half of the visitors to this page. Configure your web server to set the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` and you are done. Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 4):

I tracked down the issue
The iframe is being block by chrome detecting insecure content and blocking the iframe from loading. this only occurs when using Chrome, IE Firefox, Safari on PC work fine.
Safari and Chrome also work fine on the iPad. It appears Chrome on PC has a different set of rules and blocks the content. Selecting the shield in the URL title bar allows the content to be displayed. Pressing Ctrl shift J gives some information about what content is being blocked.
wouldn't it be nice if all the browser followed the one set of rules

Comment: Thank You for response. And how can I solve this problem, I wan in Chrome everything work correctly.

Comment: @Vahe Galstyan I try to find how to solve this problem.if it is useful,please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

iFrame doesn't support most of the things. For ex: if you have graphs in your application it won't be displayed.Use embed or object instead.

```
<object data="{{srcUrlTrusted}}" width="100%" height="800">
    <embed ng-src="{{srcUrlTrusted}}" width="100%" height="800"> </embed> 
</object>
```

Comment: why using angular? use src instead ng-src

Comment: @Diego yes for sure we can use src instead of ng-src. the above one is just a snippet from my code base.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when trying to embed a PDF. I tried both an `<iframe>` and `<embed>` approach, but they still wouldn't open in Chrome.

The solution for me was opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat and under the "Protect" tab, select "Remove Hidden Information". 
I didn't create this PDF, so I am not sure which policy, etc was causing the issue.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Remove attributes if present with

```
<iframe allow="clipboard-write"
sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-downloads allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-forms" allowfullscreen="true" src="http://assets.google.com/document.pdf">

<iframe src="http://assets.google.com/document.pdf" allowfullscreen="true">
```